# Task :expo-permissionscompileReleaseKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to create an .aab file to put the app on Google Play.I'm running React Native with Expo. I run the command `npx expo run:android --variant release`

My expo project in an old one.I have jdk 11 and gradle 3.5.3

I get the error :

```
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@5.1.2 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\@unimodules\core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.2.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter
 expo-constants@9.0.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-constants
 expo-device@2.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-device
 expo-error-recovery@1.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-file-system
 expo-font@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-font
 expo-image-loader@1.0.1 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-image-loader
 expo-keep-awake@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-keep-awake
 expo-linear-gradient@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-linear-gradient
 expo-location@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-location
 expo-permissions@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions
 expo-print@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-print
 expo-sharing@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-sharing
 expo-splash-screen@0.2.3 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-splash-screen
 expo-sqlite@8.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-sqlite
 expo-updates@0.2.14 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-updates
 expo-web-browser@8.2.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-web-browser
 unimodules-app-loader@1.0.2 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-app-loader
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.1.0 from D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface

> Configure project :react-native-fetch-blob
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :unimodules-core:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :expo-constants:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-constants\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\constants\ConstantsService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.                                     
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :expo-device:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-device\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\device\DeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :expo-file-system:processReleaseManifest
D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-file-system\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-21:20 Warning:
        provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:10 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :expo-file-system:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-file-system\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\filesystem\FileSystemModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.                                 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :expo-image-loader:compileReleaseKotlin
w: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-image-loader\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\imageloader\ImageLoaderModule.kt: (11, 42): 'SimpleTarget<Z : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java  
w: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-image-loader\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\imageloader\ImageLoaderModule.kt: (83, 22): 'SimpleTarget<Z : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :expo-location:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-location\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\location\taskConsumers\GeofencingTaskConsumer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.                  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :expo-print:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-print\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\print\PrintPDFRenderTask.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :expo-permissions:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (16, 8): Unresolved reference: com                                    
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (170, 17): Unresolved reference: PermissionAwareActivity
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (230, 19): Unresolved reference: PermissionAwareActivity
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (231, 62): Too many arguments for public final fun requestPermissions(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Array<(out) String!>!, p1: Int): Unit defined in android.app.Activity
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (231, 64): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (231, 77): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (231, 97): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-permissions:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
186 actionable tasks: 186 executed
D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: D:\FISE2\Aina\compiling\pingaina\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\run\android\spawnGradleAsync.ts:83:28)
    at assembleAsync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\run\android\spawnGradleAsync.ts:57:16)
    at actionAsync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\run\android\runAndroid.ts:145:22)
```

Package.json :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.14",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/i18n-js": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.1",
    "@types/react-native-svg-charts": "^5.0.3",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "d3-shape": "^1.3.7",
    "date-fns": "^2.12.0",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-print": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^6.0.2",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-timeline-flatlist": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-sweet-state": "^2.1.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.2.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.23",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.61.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.30.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
    "husky": ">=4",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ],
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix"
  },
  "name": "pingaina",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I tried to change versions in build.gradle :

```
 buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
 minSdkVersion = 21
 compileSdkVersion = 28
 targetSdkVersion = 28
```

I also tried to add a kotlin dependency in build.gradle.